# How to get accelerometer data outside function?

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I get x, y, z accelerometer data only inside function.

How to get these values outside too (I'm using real device, an iPhone 4)?

```
import CoreMotion
//...
var Ax: Double?
var Ay: Double?
var Az: Double?

if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable {
            self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue()) {
            (data, error) in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                var Ax = data.acceleration.x
                var Ay = data.acceleration.y
                var Az = data.acceleration.z
            }
        }

    } else {
        println("Accelerometer is not available")
    }

println("\(Ax)") // nil value
```

This is a second version, but with the same result (which one is better, if there is? I need the data of the accelerometer in the background and foreground):

```
import CoreMotion
//...
var Ax: Double?
var Ay: Double?
var Az: Double?

if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable {
        let queue = NSOperationQueue()
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(queue, withHandler: {(data: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in

            var Ax = "\(data.acceleration.x)"
            var Ay = "\(data.acceleration.y)"
            var Az = "\(data.acceleration.z)"
            }
        )

    } else {
        println("Accelerometer is not available")
    }

println("\(Ax)") // nil value
```

Comment: just remove var declaration in the handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Ax` variable is `nil` because you redefine `Ax`, `Ay`, `Az` in the handler. Also, the handler is called after the main functions ends, so the `print()` statement is called before receiving data from the accelerometer. You'll need to refactor your code to take that into consideration, maybe updating the UI in the handler.

Comment: Thanks @mbx, I changed "var Ax = data.acceleration.x" to "Ax = data.acceleration.x" but still get "nil" value...

Comment: try printing the value inside the handler

Comment: Yes I did. Inside the handler I can get the value :-(

Comment: this is because the handler is called after the main function exists. you'll need to refactor your code to take that into consideration.

Comment: Ah!, yes, you're right! I put this function in the wrong place, inside another function. Thank you very much!